# How to delete a singly linked list in C?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, free, strcmp

I'm working on a C code. I have a singly linked list, and i want to delete a node,which i don't know the position of it. My struct is this:

```
struct list_node{
  int num;
  char name[25];
  int year;
  float money;
  struct list_node *next;
};
typedef struct list_node node;
node *head=NULL;
```

I have a value which i have to compare with the node->name so it deletes the node. How can i do this? I had tried with this code to do this:

```
value=argv[2];
  temp=head;
  if(temp==NULL){
    return 0;
  }
   if(strcmp(current->name,value)==0){
    temp=head;
    head=head->next;
    free(temp);
    return 0;
  }
  p=head;
    while(p->next!=NULL){
      if(strcmp(p->next->name,value)==0){
        temp=p->next;
        p->next=temp->next;
        free(temp);
        return 0;
      }
        p=p->next;

    }
    return 0;
  }
```

but the node was not deleted. (I have a function to print the list)

Comment: *it didn't work* isn't a valid problem description. How exactly didn't it work? Please [edit] your question to make it clear.

Comment: Take a look at your code for a second, specially after the second `strcmp`. You are removing the next node, not the current node.

Comment: There's a lot missing from that code, but there's also a whole lot of code here for something that should be simple. You should probably try and break this down into smaller, more testable functions, like one that properly initializes a node, one that properly deletes it, one that unlinks it, etc. Using a test-driven development model can shake out a lot of ugly bugs quite early in the process instead of having to debug a huge block of untested code.

Comment: @Pablo It's comparing the **next** value then remove the next node. Is it wrong?

Comment: @iBug I didn't realize that the `strcmp` is actually checking `p->next`, I didn't expect that. In that context, that's not wrong. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise we are only guessing here.

Comment: Don't try to cram to problem description in the title. Try to summarize the topical nature of the problem in a simple sentence with few words.

Comment: Any time you are working with a linked-list (or other list type), before you pickup the keyboard, take out a pencil and piece of paper, draw out three nodes, the *prev* node, the *victim* node and the *next* node. Write down the specific steps needed to (1) rewire the pointers so the list without *victim* continues to function as a list, and (2) then `free` the memory associated with *victim*. It's much easier than (1) guess, (2) type, (3) compile, (4) fail, (5) repeat....

Comment: `current` is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.. I think you probably have made mistake in taking pointers to structures!

```
 {
        node* temp;
        node * ptr=head;
        if(ptr=NULL)
        {
            return 0;
        }
         else if(strcmp(ptr->name, name2)==0)
        {
            head=head->next;
            free(ptr);
            return 0;
        }
         while(ptr->next!=NULL) 
        {
            if(strcmp(ptr->next->name,  name2)==0)
            {
                temp=ptr->next;
                ptr->next=ptr->next->next;
                free(temp);
                return 0;
            }
             ptr=ptr->next;
        }
         printf("Node not found!");
         return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have a value which i have to compare with the node->name so it
>   deletes the node. How can i do this?

… not too complicated:

```
        node *curr, **prev;
        for (prev = &head; curr = *prev; prev = &curr->next)
            if (strcmp(curr->name, value) == 0)
            {
                *prev = curr->next,
                free(curr);
                break;
            }
```